# How do I determine the current operating system version in MSBuild?

Tags: windows, msbuild, msbuild-task

Is there a native or custom MSBuild task available that returns the current OS version?  Is there a binary that I could call via an Exec task?  Or is there some other option?

Edit:
Peter Lang suggested the following link:
http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/07/06/getting-the-windows-os-version-in-msbuild.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with a registry key lookup as described in [this post](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/07/06/getting-the-windows-os-version-in-msbuild.aspx).

Comment: I did come across that link earlier.  I should have put it in the original question.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for teaching me how to query registry key in msbuild - this might come handy any time.

Answer (score 1):

You could Exec this PowerShell line:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem | select Version
```

Comment: I hadn't considered running an Exec of PowerShell before.  This looks very interesting.  As it turns out, we recently implemented a custom MSBuild task that executes PowerShell scripts.

Comment: @Scott There's a lot more in this: try ServicePackMajorVersion instead of Version for example